# Layout classes from TCEFORM not showing in bootstrap_package frontend

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to add items to the layout option in the backend, either for pages or content elements. And even when I see them in the backend, I can choose one, save and it stays saved (is there when I reload) in the frontend I keep getting "frame-default" or "layout-default" or whatever other default.

This is quite clear:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

And I've done this before, it is that simple. But there must be something else in my system reverting and disabling this.
I've checked the TCEFORM tsconfig on the backend (in the info module) but I don't see anything that must be causing the issue.

Is a Typo3 11.5 with a Bootrstrap template based sitepackage. What it seemed strange to me is that the only option I had in the backend before I added these new ones was "Default" not more.

```
#
# TCEFORM
#
TCEFORM {
    pages {
        layout {
            altLabels {
                0 = Default
                1 = Product-Cards
                2 = Alternative 2
                3 = Alternative 3
                4 = Alternative 4
                5 = Alternative 5
            }
            addItems.150 = Alternative 150
        }
    }
    tt_content {
        layout {
            altLabels {
                0 = Default
                1 = Product-Cards
                2 = Alternative 2
                3 = Alternative 3
                4 = Alternative 4
                5 = Alternative 5
            }
            addItems.150 = Alternative 150
        }
    }
    tx_news_domain_model_news {
        content_elements.disabled = 1
    }
}
```

[image]

Bootstrap seems to have been adding this layout classes just fine in it's Layout. I haven't modify bootstrap partials, template or layouts.

```
<f:variable name="backgroundImageClass">{f:if(condition: backgroundImage.0, then: 'frame-has-backgroundimage', else: 'frame-no-backgroundimage')}</f:variable>
            <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame {frameSize} {frameClass} {typeClass} {layoutClass} {backgroundClass} {backgroundImageClass} {spaceBeforeClass} {spaceAfterClass}">
                <div class="frame-group-container">
                    <div class="frame-group-inner">
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds, like the options *are* added in the BE. So your `TCEFORM` is correct (and the topic is a bit misleading). If there's no change in the *FE*, we should discuss your templates/partials and look into those.

Comment: I guess you are right. Ive just assume that bootstrap package would have the layout into consideration on the templates. I haven't change the bootstrap's partials or templates, but maybe they didn't give this classes into them, I will look into it.

Comment: Sorry about the topic, I don't know how to make it better.

Comment: Did you put a `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` into your template to see what you really got?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the file:
bootstrap_package//Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentElements/Default.html

I saw that by default bootstrap package is not including this backend layout property in its ContentElements layouts. "frame_layout" IS there but just "layout" is not.
So I would need to overwrite this file and add it.
Why isn't it there?
So... I by overwriting it and adding this fluid variable in between this other ones is fixed.

```html
<f:variable name="typeClass">frame-type-{data.CType}</f:variable>
    <f:variable name="justLayout">frame-type-{data.layout}</f:variable> // Creating this variable and adding it between the classes.
    <f:variable name="layoutClass">frame-layout-{data.frame_layout}</f:variable>
    <f:variable name="backgroundClass">frame-background-{f:if(condition: data.background_color_class, else: 'none', then: data.background_color_class)}</f:variable>
    <f:variable name="spaceBeforeClass">frame-space-before-{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, else: 'none', then: data.space_before_class)}</f:variable>
    <f:variable name="spaceAfterClass">frame-space-after-{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, else: 'none', then: data.space_after_class)}</f:variable>

    <f:if condition="{data.frame_class} != none">
        <f:then>
            <f:variable name="backgroundImageClass">{f:if(condition: backgroundImage.0, then: 'frame-has-backgroundimage', else: 'frame-no-backgroundimage')}</f:variable>
            <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame {justLayout} {frameSize} {frameClass} {typeClass} {layoutClass} {backgroundClass} {backgroundImageClass} {spaceBeforeClass} {spaceAfterClass}">
                <div class="frame-group-container">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, EXT:bootstrap_package is adding a new column `frame_layout` to `tt_content` and using this in its layout. You are modifying the Core's `tt_content.layout` (without "frame_" prefix).

---

`pages.layout`seems not to be supported/used by EXT:bootstrap_package